# How to swap columns using openpyxl

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I've .xlsx file. Rows are good, values are just fine. But i need to change the columns order by list of new columns positions, e.g:
`old = [1, 2, 3, 4]`
`new = [2, 1, 4, 3]`

Docs are checked - there is no straightforward options for this problem.
I've tried to iterate over columns, so:

```py
old = {cell.column: cell.value for cell in ws[1]}.keys() # [1, 2, 3, 4]
new = [2, 1, 4, 3]

for i, col in enumerate(ws.iter_cols(max_col=old[-1]), 1):
    if old[i-1] != new[i-1]:
        for one in ws[get_column_letter(i)]:
            old_cell = one
            new_cell = ws.cell(old_cell.row, old[new[i-1]]-1)
            new_cell.value, old_cell.value = old_cell.value, new_cell.value
        old[i] = new_cell.column
        old[new_cell.column] = old_cell.column
```

...but it work only for a few cases. Probably i'm missing some general solution.

At the and it should be, for example, `old = [1, 2, 3, 4]` `new = [2, 1, 4, 3]`:

Input file:

```
x A  B  C  D 
1 A1 B1 C1 D1
2 A2 B2 C2 D2
3 A3 B3 C3 D3
4 A4 B4 C3 D4
```

Output file:

```
x A  B  C  D 
1 B1 A1 D1 C1
2 B2 A2 D2 C2
3 B3 A3 D3 C3
4 B4 A4 D3 C4
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach risks overwriting cells. I'd be tempted to move the cells from existing columns to new columns in the correct order and then delete the old ones.

```python
for c in ws['A']:
    new_cell = c.offset(column=6)
    new_cell.value = c.value

for c in ws['B']:
    new_cell = c.offset(column=5)
    new_cell.value = c.value

ws.delete_cols(min_col=1, max_col=4)
```

This is just to give you the general idea could be optimised and parametrised so you could do each row at once.

Or you could use move_range:

```python
ws.move_range(min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=1, max_row=ws.max_row, cols=5)
```

In either case be careful not to overwrite existing cells before you've moved them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first way with offset method helped me.