# How do I move an entire excel column to the left or right of its current position using python and openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel column called Erf (Column R). I need to move Erf to column C. Column C is blank so I wont be replacing any data, just moving it.
I do not have a set number of rows (my dataset changes weekly), I need to automate it such that I move the Erf column every time I run the script, without having to define a row range. Below is the code for my working environment. I have no idea how to attempt moving a column. Please help.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Source.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet']


wb.save('Source.xlsx')
```

Comment: this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080554/how-to-swap-columns-using-openpyxl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this might work
to move right

```
y = 1
x = 1
move = 1
excel = openpyxl.load_workbook("yourfile.xlsx")
sheet = excel.active

while sheet.cell(y, x).value != None:
    sheet.cell(y, x + move).value = sheet.cell(y, x).value
    sheet.cell(y, x).value = None
    y += 1
```

to move left just change move to -1